# Curl for file download via POST

Tags: curl

I use curl to send POST data, and expect to get a zip file back.  The curl POST command seems to execute Ok, and I can see that the server tries to send the zip file (dataset.zip) as an attachment, but I don't know how to get it.  Am I missing a curl option?  Please help!  This is the command + output:

```
curl -ksb "COOKIE.txt" --request POST -d params="${params}" -v "https://MYSERVER.com/downloadDatasetsByParams"
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 20 Mar 2018 23:35:13 GMT
Server Apache-Coyote/1.1 is not blacklisted
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
content-disposition: attachment; filename=dataset.zip
Content-Type: application/x-download
Set-Cookie: X_Email=kUser@mserver.com
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Failed writing body (0 != 4096)
Failed writing data
Marked for [closure]: Transfer returned error
multi_done
stopped the pause stream!
Closing connection 0
The cache now contains 0 members
TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS alert, Client hello (1):
```

Answer (score 0):

Newbie mistake.  It works with the -o option:
-o "outputfile.txt"